# Ursina models scale

Tags: python, ursina

I'm building a game in ursina and for some Entity's I use my own texture images models->
I did try all models type offered by the framework (ex: quad,cube etc...)[for example my cat hero is taking damage from the red box even if its not actually hitting because the obj is much bigger than the image..its there a way to scale it?)
But I'm not able to scale them properly so the actual entity obj is mush bigger than the image:
Please see the image bellow:
The code for those 3 entities is here:

```
wall = Entity(model='quad', scale=(2,3), x=-3,
              collider='box', color=color.white,texture='images/cat_tower.png')
level = Entity(model='quad', color=color.white, scale=(3, 1), x=4, collider='box',texture='images/cat_slider_1')
trap = Entity(model='quad', scale=(2,2, 2), x=-5, y=1, collider='box', texture=f'images/trap.png',color=color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Do your textures contain a significant transparent portion?

Comment: No it does not, i use paint3d for the images and the transparaceny is off, but thanks anways: )

Comment: Can you provide one of the images you use as textures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this problem seems that the problem was not in the code itself ( or ursina framework) but in the way I edited the PNG/JPG images objects-> even if I did not have the TRANSPARENCY set on each of them, seems that the issue was when I did crop them in Paint3D and set the transparency off I need to scale the image to fit  totally in the object inside paint 3d white scheme( not to the scale I have it after I did magic select and crop it..)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).